# numerical linear algebra 101

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, numerical-linear-algebra

since I'm a programmer and I need linear algebra, I'm starting considering how to teach myself a little of numerical linear algebra, not really optimize things right from the start, but I would like to get how to decompose and "linearize" a matrix or a vector in a form that can be written on a single line or in a less "cryptic" way.

For example I would like to find a resource that when mentioning vector normalization, it will outline the fact that I can normalize a vector with just a square root to make my life "easier" and think more in an algebraic way instead of in a more cryptic way.

As I mentioned earlier I also would like to skip the optimizations for now, so I would like to not have a resource that tells me that a division is not cheap and a multiplication is better in terms of computation power used. I would like to do that because I already have this kind of notions and at this point performances are not my point, my point is really just how to transpose a matrix or a vector into common algebra and how to perform all the linear algebra operations in "standard" calculus.

Considering my goals and my field, where and with what should I start ?

Comment: Have you looked at [*CAS programs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) inclusing Matlab and the spinoffs? Also, languages like Haskell? Just things to chew on. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti no but I would like to stick with plain old C or C++, definitely not Matlab or other libs because my point is not about using a linear algebra system, it's about how to code one from the ground up.

Comment: I am saying you can consider those CAS approaches as some of them are very well understood for the API to coding it up. You can also look at books by Golub, by Horn, by Trefthen as ways of specifying things. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti can you please give links about those books, I mean a more specific reference to this titles ? I also get what are you saying about existing implementations and I already have done something like that, the point is that often times the implementations are more like a mix between advanced programming techniques and obscure ( for me, for now ) numerical methods, so beside the programming part, I wouldn't get much out of them considering my actual know-how on the math side.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Topics-Matrix-Analysis-Roger-Horn/dp/0521467136/ref=pd_sim_b_1, http://www.amazon.com/Computations-Hopkins-Studies-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/0801854148, http://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Linear-Algebra-Lloyd-Trefethen/dp/0898713617/ref=pd_sim_b_1, http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Numerical-Linear-Algebra-Demmel/dp/0898713897/ref=pd_sim_b_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would pick up "Linear Algebra" by Strang and "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Trefethen and Bau.  Those will get you well on your way, along with math.stackexchange and [scicomp.stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at those books, nice to know that we also got a dedicated website for computation.

Comment: Is there any consensus about which of Strang's linear algebra books is better?  I've always been partial to Linear Algebra and its Applications, but many people recommend his Introduction to Linear Algebra.

Comment: @littleO hmm, not sure.  I have "Introduction", but I'm sure they're both good.